# Image data still there even though it is deleted before submitting form

Tags: jquery, html

Apologize for the title. Below are my issue :

I had DIY-ed an image thumbnail when selecting image file from user computer with the option of able to remove the selected image and choose a new one.

When I click on the upload button, it has uploaded the same image that I have last chosen. What I don't get it is, why does it also have the image if I clicked on the delete image button before uploading?

Below are my HTML code :

```
<input id="trip-photo1" type="file" class="trip-ul-photo-img" name="trip-photo[]">
<label for="trip-photo1"></label>
```

The above is 1 of the 5 input I have.

Below are my jQuery code :

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.trip-ul-photo-img', function(){
        var photo_wrapper       =   $(".trip-ul-photo"); //Fields wrapper
        var photo_button        =   $(".btn-trip-ul-photo"); //Add button ID
        var reader              =   new FileReader();
        var photo               =   $(this);
        var btn_str             =   '';
            btn_str             +=  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-photo-del" role="button">X</button>';

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
            var img_str     =   '';
                img_str     +=  '<img class="pro-set-up-photo-preview" src="' + e.target.result + '" />'
            photo.parent().append(img_str, btn_str);
        };

        // read the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-photo-del', function(){
        $(this).parent(".trip-ul-photo-group").next(".trip-ul-photo-cap-wrapper").children("input, p").remove();
        $(this).parent(".trip-ul-photo-group").children("img, button").remove();
    });
```

I have totally no idea what is going on as this is also my first time DIY the delete selected image myself.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Issue lies on this is the default behaviour of a file input whenever you select any file. Just set the data to null when deleting the preview image.